# Latest 2016 Paypal IPN Code always return INVALID response

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I know there's alot of question regarding this inquiry but i cant find the right answer to asses my needs. Here is my current code for my project. and I always receives INVALID response from paypal using Paypal Sandbox IPN Simulator.

Can someone point me whats wrong with my code, i appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php

$post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_array = explode('&', $post_data);
$dataFromPayPal = array();
foreach ($post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $dataFromPayPal[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($dataFromPayPal as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);


$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));

if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    echo "INVALID";
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {


$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];


    //STORE temporary info to table
    //================
    require 'config.php';

    $query = "INSERT INTO Payments (ItemName,ItemNumber,PayStatus,PayAmount,PayCurrency,PayTransID,PayEmail,RecEmail) 
            VALUES('$item_name', '$item_number', '$payment_status', '$payment_amount', '$payment_currency', '$txn_id', '$payer_email', '$receiver_email')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    mysqli_close($con);


}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer for my inquiry. You can use this code as your final IPN for Sandbox or Live. With the following consideration:

1. Be sure to place your IPN listener to ->My selling tools -> instant payment notifications Section.
2. Do not use IPN Simulator in sandbox, it will always return INVALID.
3. Create and Use an actual Sandbox Button, but DO NOT put your IPN listener to RETURN PAGE that says "Take customers to this URL when they finish checkout".

That's all of it. I hope this will help.

And here is the working code:

```
<?php
$post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_array = explode('&', $post_data);
$dataFromPayPal = array();
foreach ($post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $dataFromPayPal[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($dataFromPayPal as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
//use https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr in case you are testing this on a PayPal Sanbox environment
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);



if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        echo "INVALID";
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        echo "VALID";
}

?>
```